# Orthogonal matrix and subspace

Tags: orthogonality, invariant-subspace

I am facing some difficulties proving the below statement:

Let B be an NxN orthogonal matrix, and U is a subspace of Rn.

I want to prove that :

```
for all u ∈ U , w ∈ U⊥:
Bu ⊥ Bw
```

I would appriciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $\langle\rangle\;$ the inner product in that space, then:

$$\langle Bu,Bw\rangle=\langle u,B^*Bw\rangle$$

and now just remember (1) what being "an orthogonal matrix" means, and (2) where did you take $\;u,\,w\;$ from...

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I am still not sure I get this , is there any chance for a more detailed answer?

Comment: @user3586606 I think you must know **something** about orthogonal matrices, otherwise it is like you're asking someone else to do your homework for you...You must either know that $\;B^*B=BB^*=I\;$ , or else, even easier, that $\;\langle Bu,Bw\rangle=\langle u,w\rangle\;$ ...

Comment: Of course I know that , I am just not sure what those ⟨ ⟩ mean.  I know that ||Bu|| = ||u|| , and I know that (u * w) = 0.  how this statement ⟨Bu,Bw⟩=⟨u,B∗Bw⟩ helps me?